# Dynamic binding doesn't work correctly on fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, dynamic-binding

I have a hierarchy of fragments:

```
AbsFragm
|_ConcFrag1
|_ConcFrag2
|_ConcFrag3
```

AbsFragm has the abstract method

```
abstract int getColor()
```

which every subClass overrides. My ConcFrags are shown within a viewPager, and when I switch between pages the colors shown are not the right ones:
ConcFrag1 has ConcFrag2 color, and so on.
What does this problem depend on?